# How to rotate rows by index into columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe that looks like this:

```
  title      answer
0  aa         zz
1  bb         xx
2  cc         yy
3  dd         ll
```

I want to rotate by index value and reset index the rows as index and value for only two rows like this:

```
    bb       cc
0   xx       yy
```

How do I do this?

I tried Transpose:

```
df[['title','answer']].T
```

but that puts integer values in the column headers and not sure how to select by index number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

we can set `title` as the index and then transpose, the reason you get integers is because your tranposing on the index

```
df_new = df.set_index('title').T

print(df_new)

title   aa  bb  cc  dd
answer  zz  xx  yy  ll
```

if you want to get rid of the index as well :

```
df_new = df.set_index('title').T.reset_index(drop=True)
df_new.columns.name = ''
```

---

```
print(df_new)
   aa  bb  cc  dd
0  zz  xx  yy  ll
```

Comment: @anky_91 very nice with the `df.to_numpy()` how does this handle multiple columns? will it infer the first column as the index?

Comment: @RustyShackleford you are most welcome my friend, happy coding :)